# Dynamically loading Vim scripts

Tags: vim

In my dotfiles configuration I'm trying to build it so that I can have *.vim files from a certain folder loaded in automatically. To do so I add the following piece of code to my `.vimrc` file:

```
function PluginConfigs ()
    let vimscripts = split(globpath("$ZSH/vim", '*.vim'), '\n')
    for i in vimscripts
        echom i
        source i
    endfor
endfunction
call PluginConfigs()
```

When I open Vim now I get the following output:

```
/home/davejlong/.dotfiles/vim/dispatch.vim
Error detected while processing function PluginConfigs:
line    4:
E484: Can't open file i
/home/davejlong/.dotfiles/vim/leaders.vim
E484: Can't open file i
/home/davejlong/.dotfiles/vim/matchtagalways.vim
E484: Can't open file i
/home/davejlong/.dotfiles/vim/neocomplete.vim
E484: Can't open file i
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I'm not sure why I can't use the variable `i` in the `source` command.

Comment: You may want to check out `:h :runtime` to source your files. You may also want to look at using the `after` directory, but this is not applicable in all cases. See `:h vimfiles` for more information on the `~/.vim` file structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I figured it out right after posting the question. I changed the function to this and it works:

```
function PluginConfigs ()
    let vimscripts = split(globpath("$ZSH/vim", '*.vim'), '\n')
    for i in vimscripts
        exec ":source " . i
    endfor
endfunction
call PluginConfigs()
```

It appears that you need to use `exec` to source a file from a variable.

Comment: You need `:execute` whenever you want to run a command with some concatenated text.